# Programmatic Remote Access to the Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have a requirement to implement a batch processing system that will run outside of Google App Engine (GAE) to batch process data from an RDBMS and insert it into GAE.

The `appcfg.py` does this from various input files but I would like to do it "by hand" using some API so I can fully control the lifecycle of the process. Is there a public API that is used internally by `appcfg.py`?

I would write a daemon in Python that runs on my internal server and monitors certain MySQL tables. Under the correct conditions, it would grab data from MySQL, process it, and post it using the GAE RemoteAPI to the GAE application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like you already know what to do. in your own words: "grab data from MySQL, process it, and post it using the GAE RemoteAPI." the [remote api docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html) even have examples that write to the datastore.

Comment: Sorry that took me so long, I got distracted.

Comment: go to this [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/remoteapi) for the doc on remote api access from an go application.

Answer (score 0):

What you could probably do (If I understand right what your problem is) is using the [Task Queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/). With that you could define a Task that does what you expect it to do;

Lets say you want to insert something into GAE-datastore. prepare the insert file on some server. Than go to your application and prepare an "Start Insert Task". By clicking on that a background task will start, read that file and insert it into the datastore.

Furthermore, if that task is daily performed you could invoke the task creation with a cron job.

However, if you could say more about the work you have to perform it would be easier :-P

Comment: You still could do that passive with cron jobs because I don't think there exist an "active" API for that. However what is still possible is to send that in as a form submit. So as normal HTTPRequests but that becomes tricky regarding security